# Can not open Workspace in Enterprise Edition Studio on Windows, but I can on Community Edition Studio

Tags: eclipse, mule, esb

I installed the Windows version Enterprise Edition of the Studio just now

I am runnin Java 1.7

I created a new foleder in Windows

```
Reporting ID: xxx
Studio PID: STUDIO-84317557-2183-4e51-bd7d-eb544575b4e0-14153784551780768

System OS: Windows Server 2008-6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1-x86
Java Version: IBM Corporation-1.6.0
Studio Version: 4.1.0.201410170001
Runtime Version: 


Project Structure: 



Error Description: 
Unable to create project.

Error Stacktrace: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.wizards.newproject.MuleNewProjectWizard.doPerformFinish(MuleNewProjectWizard.java:124)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.wizards.newproject.MuleNewProjectWizard.performFinish(MuleNewProjectWizard.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.project.OpenMuleNewProjectWizardAction.run(OpenMuleNewProjectWizardAction.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.runAction(IntroURL.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.doExecute(IntroURL.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL$1.run(IntroURL.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.execute(IntroURL.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.presentations.BrowserIntroPartLocationListener.changing(BrowserIntroPartLocationListener.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE$7.handleEvent(IE.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventTable.sendEvent(OleEventTable.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.notifyListener(OleEventSink.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.Invoke(OleEventSink.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.access$1(OleEventSink.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink$1.method6(OleEventSink.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
    at org.mule.tooling.core.io.MuleResourceUtils.getInputFactory(MuleResourceUtils.java:109)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.io.MuleResourceUtils.<clinit>(MuleResourceUtils.java:61)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.impl.model.MuleProjectImpl.save(MuleProjectImpl.java:399)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.utils.CoreUtils.createMuleProject(CoreUtils.java:242)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.wizards.newproject.CreateNewMuleProjectRunnable.run(CreateNewMuleProjectRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    ... 51 more
```

Is this because I have a java JRE installed instead of a JDK

I can successfully run the Comunity Edition of the Studio and create workspace and projects with the JRE I have

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC since 3.3 there is not such thing as an Enterprise Version of Studio.

Therefor, if you are using such an old version you can either:

- upgrade to the lastest version that is the same for both community or enterprise
- use Java 1.6